# Javascript self-invoking function and ajax callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, execution

I am a bit confused by the following. I am working on the asp.net mvc. I have an ajax call to return to refresh a partial view which contains a self-executing js function. I also have a callback function on the ajax done event. I was intrigued by the fact that the self-executing js function is only fired on the first time when the partial view is loaded. However, when the ajax call complete, the callback function would be triggered but the self-executing function was not. My concept make me believe that the self-executing function should be parsed by the DOM and executed immediately when the partial view has rendered. Does anyone encounter this situation? What is the cause of the problem? Thanks.

Comment: maybe you should show the code that goes along with the explanation....

Comment: An IIFE is just called once, when the code containing it is executed. It's just like inline code, it just creates a new scope for its variables. Callback functions are called when the event they're associated with happens.

Comment: Oh I see. I did not know the IIFE is just called once. Now I got it. Thanks so much.